# Bash script not recording

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So, here i am, playing with some bash scripts, and there is something that doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

script -c \
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade &&

exit

echo "(Not important for the question)"
```

I want to run the usual update and upgrade stuff, and also record the output, but when i run the script, it only says that the script started to record in apt-get, shows the usage of sudo ( `usage: sudo -h` is the first line ), and says that the sript is done. After that it starts the sudo stuff.

What do i need to do in order to record the output of the update&upgrade task? In general, **how can i record the output of an entire shell script?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update &> update.log
apt-get -y upgrade &> upgrade.log

echo "all done"
```

Save this script as `run_updates.sh`, make it executable with `chmod 755 run_updates.sh` and run it with `sudo ./run_updates.sh`.
If you want to save all output in one file, remove the `&> updates.log` and `&> upgrades.log` from the script and run the script as `sudo./run_updates.sh &> run_updates.log`

---

**Explanation of the script:**

- `apt-get update &> update.log` runs `apt-get update` and saves the output in `update.log`
- `apt-get -y upgrade &> upgrade.log` runs `apt-get upgrade` and saves the output in `upgrade.log`. The `-y` prevents apt from asking to continue (it assumes "yes")

---

**A note on redirections:**
You can use the redirections below to "send" output from a command or script to a file.

- `&>` redirects STDOUT and STDERR
- `>` or `1>` redirects STDOUT
- `2>` redirects STDERR

---

**A note on sudo:**
This is probably the reason why you got errors. When running a command that needs `sudo` in a script, it is a good idea to put the command without `sudo` in the script and run the script with `sudo`. Otherwise, you would have to give your sudo password to the script in some way, which is bad.

---

Edit:
In the following code, the output of both apt commands is redirected to `update.log`. The double `>` (`>>`) is used to append data to a file (instead of replacing it)

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update &> update.log
apt-get -y upgrade &>> update.log

echo "all done"
```

Comment: I didn't realize i could run the script itself as `sudo`. It'll make my life easier, thanks. About the redirection, is it possible to write something in the script to automatically record the output of both commands into the same file instead of writing the output on separate files?

Comment: @macacomen98 see my edit **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

In general, to log the output of the entire script, redirect the output of the entire script:

```
exec &> some.log
# Or, when using `/bin/sh`:
# exec >some.log 2>&1
```

[The `exec` builtin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/exec.1posix) is often used to change the open file descriptors or add new file descriptors (the sources and destinations of input and output) for the shell.

For example, given `example.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec &> some.log
ls foo
echo foo
```

On running:

```
$ ./example.sh
$ cat some.log
ls: foo: No such file or directory
foo
```

If you want both output to screen and to a file, use `tee` with process substitution:

```
exec &> >(tee some.log)
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for a script, just do it in one line using Bash redirections and `tee`:

```
{ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade ; } |& tee output.txt
```

In case you want to append the output to an existing logfile, add the `-a` option after `tee`.

---

To explain what it does:

- `{ ... ; }` groups the `...` commands inside, so that the output redirections we will perform apply to all commands and not just the last one. Please pay attention on the space after `{` and before `}` as well as on the semicolon `;` after all commands! *(thanks @kos for telling me to avoid spawning a subshell)*
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` are the example commands we want to run and record here. You may exchange this whole part with whatever you like.
- `|&` (the "pipe") redirects both output streams (STDERR/standard error and STDOUT/standard output) of the command left of it to the STDIN (standard input) of the command on the right. *(thanks @muru for teaching me about the `&` to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR)*
- `tee output.txt` copies everything it reads from STDIN to STDOUT and also saves it to `output.txt`. If the target file already exists, it will get overwritten silently. You can append to the file instead if you use `tee -a output.txt`.

Comment: About the script, i usually do this on the terminal. I use the script just for a little bit of fun and to learn some stuff. But thanks for the note on the redirections STERR and STDOUT to the same file, didn´t know i could do that.

Comment: Since you're there, you could also drop `tee`: `(sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade) >output.txt 2>&1`. And if you want to go even further, you could also avoid to spawn the subshell: `{ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade; } >output.txt 2>&1` ;)

Comment: Bash has `|&` for `2>&1 |`.

Comment: @kos I keep the `tee`, because usually the people still want to see what the command does. But the curly braces seem like an improvement.

Comment: @muru Oh, really! I did not know about that yet. Strange, but thanks. Now I learned something again. :-)

Comment: @muru About that, if i write `echo "hello" 2>&1 | tee file.txt` it works fine, but if i write `echo "hello" |& tee file.txt` it does not work as expected. It only shows `Syntax error: "&" unexpected`. Atention: I'm writing this in the script, not in the terminal. If i type `echo "hello" |& tee file.txt` on the terminal it works, but on the script it doesn't.

Comment: @macacomen98 Does your script start with `#! /bin/bash`?  How are you running the script?

Comment: @muru I start the script in the terminal using `sh file.txt` and yes, it's a bash script started with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @macacomen98 If you're running it `sh file.txt`, then you're not running it in bash.

Comment: Ups, my bad... I'm new in Linux, there's much stuff i don't understand right. So how do i make it run in bash?

Comment: @macacomen98 `./file.txt` or `bash file.txt`